# ROS: Google-cartographer / Mapping

Tags: c++, google-api, camera, mapping, ros

I have to create a map, to do so I installed google cartographer and I'm using a 3D camera with whom I got the data of my surrounding. I am reading the documentation to the cartographer but I cant find the place where it is explaining to me how i do the mapping.

I know i have to start rviz but I don't know what the next step is. Am I getting the data of the camera in rviz?
And is there any Youtube tutorial I can follow or something?

Comment: I do not know what do you want exactly, but there is a complete example using a [turtlebot and a 3D sensor with Cartographer](https://google-cartographer-ros-for-turtlebots.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: No i want to use it without a simulator. I have my own robot and sensor

Comment: Yes, but there you will see how the connections between the different nodes is done and what things do you need to feed to the Cartographer.

Comment: I'm looking at the demo_depth_camera_3d.launch. Do I have to call all the files the launch file does? I know i have to write them new by myself and I don't have to call the turtlebot files.

Answer (score 0):

So for everyone who struggles to build a map with google cartographer. There are 4 inputs google cartographer awaits:

```
1. tf tree
2. point cloud/laser scan
3. odometry
(4. imu if you try to build a 3d map)
```

The first thing you should do is to config your urdf file. This file is building your tf tree. The file describes, how your robot/system is build.

Then you need a laser sensor or a rgbd. If the laser sensor is publishing the topic /scan then you don't need to do a remap. The same is for the point cloud: if you camera publishes the topic /points then you don't have to do anything here. But if not you need to do a remap in the your launch file.

You need an odometry. For this you could look on your own for tutorials. If you do not have one, you can set in the .lua file provide_odom_frame to true.

If you are working on a 2d map you are finished here and you could run your launch file and the mapping should start. But if you have a 3d, you still need to run the imu.

You will reallize that the quality of your map is very poorly. For this you can look in the tuning methodology of google cartographer: https://google-cartographer-ros.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tuning.html

I hope this helps